# parsing soap response without using ksoap in android

Tags: android, soap, wsdl

for accesing a wsdl servise from android am using the following

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BASIC_URL);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(SoapRequest, HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setChunked(true);

        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", SoapAction);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type",   "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.addHeader(header);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       // response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        return httpResponse;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

where **SoapRequest** is a soap string ,got response from server but how to parse soap response since am not using **HttpTransportSE** and **ksoap** i dont have a soap object as response.

1. is this the correct way to access wsdl servise from android?
2. can i convert soap object to xml or json and then parse it

sample response is

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org /soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
   <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <GetResult>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns=""   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
           <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="First">
                       <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element name="FirstElement" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                       </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                 </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
           <NewDataSet xmlns="">
              <Exception diffgr:id="Exception1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                 <ex_id>12</ex_id>
              </Exception>               
              <Second diffgr:id="Second" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                 <SecondElement>66</SecondElement>
              </Second>
           </NewDataSet>
     </GetResult>
  </GetResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can parse Soap response as parsing a xml.Using xmlpull parser we can extract xml tags.Think theirs no need of **HttpTransportSE** and **ksoap**

```
  public void fetchXML(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                XmlPullParserFactory   xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
                        , false);
                myparser.setInput(new StringReader("Soap response here"));
                parseXML(myparser);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

public void parseXML(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;
    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name=myParser.getName();
            switch (event){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(name.equals("ex_id")){
                        Log.i("----", text);
                    }

                    break;
            }
            event = myParser.next();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```